# array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in drupal_schema_fields_sql()?

Tags: database

i have developed a custom module which will calculate the employee salary . I have created the hook_schema() like this

This is mymodule.install file with two entities

```
function payroll_schema() {
$schema['payroll'] = array(
  'description' => 'A detail payroll structure for an employee',
  'fields' => array(
    'payroll_id' => array(
      'description' => 'payroll id',//this is my primary key.
      'type' => 'serial',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'paid_days' => array(
      'description' => 'Working days of an employee',
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
  ...
  ...
  'primary_key' => array('payroll_id'),
);
$schema['payroll_item'] = array(
  'description' => 'Details of payroll items',
  'fields' => array(
    'item_id' => array(
      'description' => 'item_id',
      'type' => 'serial',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'payroll_items_id' => array(
      'description' => 'Payroll id', //foreign key
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    ...
    ...

  ),
  'primary key' => array('item_id'),
  'foreign keys' => array(
    'payroll_items_id' => array(
      'table' => 'payroll',
      'columns' => array('payroll_items_id' => 'payroll_id'),
    ),
   ),
);
}
```

Here is the mymodule.module file with hook_entity_info()

```
function payroll_entity_info() {
  $return['payroll'] = array(
    'label' => t('Payroll'),
    'entity class' => 'Payroll',
    'controller class' => 'PayrollController',
    'base table' => 'payroll',
    'fieldable' => TRUE,
    'entity keys' => array(
      'id' => 'payroll_id',
      'label' => 'Payroll id',
    ),
    'module' => 'payroll',
    'view modes' => array(
    'full' => array(
       'label' => t('Full content'),
       'custom settings' => FALSE,
       ),
    ),
  );
  $return['payroll_item'] = array(
    'label' => t('Payroll Item'),
    'entity class' => 'PayrollItem',
    'controller class' => 'PayrollItemController',
    'base table' => 'payroll_item',
    'fieldable' => FALSE,
    'entity keys' => array(
      'id' => 'item_id',
      'label' => 'Item id',
    ),
    'module' => 'payroll',
    'view modes' => array(
    'full' => array(
      'label' => t('Full content'),
      'custom settings' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $return;
}
```

Here is the entity_load ()

```
function payroll_load($id) {
  $payrolls = entity_load('payroll', array($id));
  return reset($payrolls);
}
```

And here is my mymodule.controller.inc

```
class PayrollController extends DrupalDefaultEntityController {
  public function __construct($payroll) {
  parent::__construct('payroll');
  }
  public function create() {
  $payrolls = new StdClass();
  return $payrolls;
  }
}
class PayrollItemController extends DrupalDefaultEntityController {
  public function __construct($payroll_items) {
  parent::__construct('payroll_item');
  }
  public function create() {
  $payroll_items = new StdClass();
  return $payroll_items;
  }
}
```

When i am trying to install a module it gives a error as:

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   drupal_schema_fields_sql()  (line 6969 of
>   mylocation/includes/common.inc).

Can you tell me where i may made any mistake ??

Comment: `return $schema;` missing. i think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've forgotten to return anything from your implementation of `hook_schema()`.

Just add `return $schema;` to the end of the function, and re-install your module.

Comment: That's it. Since `hook_schema()` doesn't get any parameter by reference, it needs to return a value.

Comment: but still payroll table has not created in the database.

Comment: You need to uninstall and re-install the module, not disable  and re-enable it.

Comment: yah its working great job